# Is it possible to use mounts and heredocs in the same RUN command in a dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm using docker 24.0.1 on an Ubuntu 22.04 install

Given the following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/apt/cache << EOT
  apt-get update -qq
  apt-get install -y apt-utils
EOT
```

When I run the build for this file, I get:

```
dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     
   5 |     RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/apt/cache << EOT
   6 | >>>   apt-get update -qq
   7 |       apt-get install -y apt-utils
   8 |     EOT
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 6: unknown instruction: apt-get
```

I'm not sure why the two features would be incompatible with one another, but given they're newer features, maybe they are. Has anyone had success using both together? Is there something I'm missing to do so?

Comment: The examples in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#here-documents) don't have a space between `<<` and `EOT`; is that space significant?  The [referenced section of the POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) more explicitly says there can't be a space there.

Answer (score 1):

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) caught my error - the typo of the extra space was what caught me off. removing that space fixed the build.